# Docker compose doesn't save data in volume

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to run Kafka with docker-compose. I got this yml file:

```yaml
version: '3'


services:
  zookeeper:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-zookeeper:${TAG}
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - ./zoo:/var/lib/zookeeper

  broker:
    image: ${REPOSITORY}/cp-kafka:${TAG}
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
    volumes:
      - ./broker:/var/lib/kafka
```

I ran in the directory with docker-compose.yml file a command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

After that folders `./broker` and `./zoo` appear in my directory. Inside they have a structure like inside the containers (`./zoo/data`, `./broker/data`). But there are no files in the dirs.

I tried

```
docker-compose exec broker ls /var/lib/kafka/data
```

and I saw folders and files about default topics

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This comes down to the interaction between [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) (as declared in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/master/kafka/Dockerfile.deb8#L68)), and the volume that you are tyring to mound as part of the [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).

If you inspect each container's Dockerfile, you'll see that it has volumes declared, which you can also see from inspecting it. Here's what it looks like when using your configuration:

```
➜ docker inspect zookeeper|jq '.[].Mounts[] | .Type ,.Destination'
"volume"
"/etc/zookeeper/secrets"
"bind"
"/var/lib/zookeeper"
"volume"
"/var/lib/zookeeper/log"
"volume"
"/var/lib/zookeeper/data"
```

You'll notice that there are two volumes (which are declared in the image itself, i.e. from the Dockerfile) against the specific data paths for ZK

- `/var/lib/zookeeper/log`
- `/var/lib/zookeeper/data`

*In addition*, there is the bind mount from the Docker Compose :

- `/var/lib/zookeeper/`

These clash, which explains the problem you're seeing.

A similar pattern exists for the broker.

---

So in short, you need to mount a local host directory per *specific volume* in the image:

```yaml
---
version: '3'


services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes: 
      - ./zoo/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./zoo/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
    volumes: 
      - ./broker/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

With this done we can see there's no conflicts in the container paths:

```
➜ docker inspect zookeeper|jq '.[].Mounts '
[
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/private/tmp/zoo/log",
    "Destination": "/var/lib/zookeeper/log",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/private/tmp/zoo/data",
    "Destination": "/var/lib/zookeeper/data",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "6cbb584e0d9aa2f119869b264544f587909d9f417fc553a7bb2954dd28ecb8ea",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/6cbb584e0d9aa2f119869b264544f587909d9f417fc553a7bb2954dd28ecb8ea/_data",
    "Destination": "/etc/zookeeper/secrets",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
]
```

and data from the containers:

```
➜ docker exec zookeeper ls -l /var/lib/zookeeper/data /var/lib/zookeeper/log
/var/lib/zookeeper/data:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 96 Apr  3 08:59 version-2

/var/lib/zookeeper/log:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 96 Apr  3 08:59 version-2

➜ docker exec broker ls -l /var/lib/kafka/data
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 192 Apr  3 08:59 __confluent.support.metrics-0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Apr  3 08:59 cleaner-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4 Apr  3 09:01 log-start-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  88 Apr  3 08:59 meta.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36 Apr  3 09:01 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36 Apr  3 09:02 replication-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Apr  3 08:30 wibble
```

is stored on the local host:

```
➜ ls -l broker/data zoo/data zoo/log
broker/data:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  6 rmoff  wheel  192  3 Apr 09:59 __confluent.support.metrics-0
-rw-r--r--  1 rmoff  wheel    0  3 Apr 09:59 cleaner-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r--  1 rmoff  wheel    4  3 Apr 10:00 log-start-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r--  1 rmoff  wheel   88  3 Apr 09:59 meta.properties
-rw-r--r--  1 rmoff  wheel   36  3 Apr 10:00 recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r--  1 rmoff  wheel   36  3 Apr 10:01 replication-offset-checkpoint
-rw-r--r--  1 rmoff  wheel    0  3 Apr 09:30 wibble

zoo/data:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 rmoff  wheel  96  3 Apr 09:59 version-2

zoo/log:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 rmoff  wheel  96  3 Apr 09:59 version-2
```

See also [Data Volumes for Kafka and ZooKeeper](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/operations/external-volumes.html#data-volumes-for-kafka-and-zk)

Comment: Just to make things clearer. The Kafka broker has two volumes defined in the dockerfile: /var/lib/kafka/data and /etc/kafka/secrets. You MUST bind both in order for the bind mount to work. If you only bind one, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Robin's answer:

If you don't want to mount a directory directly but use docker's named volumes instead, you can still do it.
You can refer to the docker-compose file which i have used to get this working.

Link - https://github.com/girishyt/kafka-docker-compose/blob/main/docker-compose-simple.yml